# How many snowspeeders (T-47) participated in the Battle of Hoth according to canon?

Tags: star-wars, statistics

How many snowspeeders (T-47) participated in the Battle of Hoth according to canon?

I will take calculations based on any canon texts (G- to C- canon); or calculated by movie visuals.

I would accept game canon if well proven and no movie/book canon contradicts that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Twelve, according to [the script](https://web.archive.org/web/20111223111136/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/esb-script.shtml):

> EXTERIOR: HOTH -- ICE PLAIN -- SNOW TRENCH
>
> The Rebel troops aim their weapons at the horizon as
> explosions erupt all around them. They are nervous and their
> grip on their weapons tightens from the cold and from fear.
> Behind the troops **a dozen snowspeeders** race through the
> sky.

Answer (score 1):

The [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(novel)) mentions that there are twelve speeders.

> Brilliant billows of orange and yellow flames exploded from the walker
>   guns. Nervously the Rebel troopers aimed their weapons at the walkers,
>   each soldier feeling icy, unseen fingers pierce his body.
>
> **Of the twelve snowspeeders, four took the lead, soaring at full
>   throttle as they moved toward the enemy.** One All Terrain Armored
>   Transport machine fired, barely missing the banking craft. A burst of
>   gunfire blew another speeder into a ball of flaming oblivion that lit
>   up the sky.